# How do i find out solutions of F(x) = F^(-1) (x) which dont lie on y=x

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, inverse-function

Okay, recently life got complicated when i realised that all solutions of $F(x) = F^{-1}  (x) $ DON'T LIE ON $y=x$.[image]

[image]

How can i found these types of solutions **without finding the inverse** and then solving with the original function?

Like , i could have found some solutions putting $x=F(x)$ , but i can't find the rest.

Comment: I mean as in given a specufic function f(x) i wanna find solutions to f(x)=f inverse (x)

Comment: I don't need a function that always satisfies f(x) = f inverse (x)

Comment: Well, you could take $F$ of both sides, and then you'd be solving $F(F(x)) = x$. There's no need to try to compute $F^{-1}$; you just need to compose $F$ with itself. If you're fine with solving equations of the form $x = F(x)$, then this should be little extra trouble.

Comment: Talking of functions such as -x+sinx+20, composition gives a pretty scary vibe to me...u will hv terms like sin(-x +sinx+20) ... i don't like the look of it

Comment: Of course, since the above function i just talked about is a pretty well behaved function oscillating about a line, it is easy to just solve it with the line... however i wud like a general solution for a general bad behaved function